# Python return instance of a different class from class instead of self

Tags: python, class

I am going to try my best to explain what I am trying to accomplish. I am trying to return an instance of a new class from a class instead of return `self`. Please refer to the comments in the example code.

```py
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def methoda(self):
        return len(self.a)


class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, lol):
        self.lol = lol
        self.test = Test(self.lol)

    def __call__(self):
        return self.test # this isnt going to work


c = SomeClass('bar')
print(c) # trying to access the Test class attributes and methods  here
# so in the above example, i want to do
# print(c.a) # print bar
# print(c.length() # print 3
```

`__repr__` and `__str__` wouldnt work in this case because I am trying to get the `Test` class object back.
Other things i have tried in `SomeClass` is having something like `self.test = Test(self.lol)`, but that doesnt seem to quite do what I want.

How can I do this?

Comment: `print(c())`? You're having the object act as a function, so you'll need to call it.

Comment: AH! That was a simple enough slip. Thanks @Carcigenicate. Is there something I can do to access it more like a property instead of calling it?

Comment: You can just access it using `c.test`. You already have it as an attribute.

Comment: You ate changing defualt attribute access behavior so there is nothing clean about it but you could override __getattr__ to return test attributes if they are not found on the calling object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the `__getattr__` method of `SomeClass` so that attributes not defined in a `SomeClass` object can be delegated to `self.test`:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def methoda(self):
        return len(self.a)

class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, lol):
        self.lol = lol
        self.test = Test(self.lol)

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return getattr(self.test, item)

c = SomeClass('bar')
print(c.methoda())
```

This outputs:

```
3
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. The only tiny issue that I am facing (and i didnt explain it properly) is that if a method in `SomeClass` modifies lol, like `self.lol * 2`, when I do `print(c.a)`, it will return `bar`, and not `barbar`. Anyway how to address this? My guess is to move `self.test = Test(self.lol)` somewhere else, but not sure where

Comment: It sounds like you don't need the `Test` class at all, but simply a `property`-decorated method that returns `self.lol * 2` then.

Comment: Actually I figured it out. Your answer really taught me about delegating to other classes. In my code, there is a lot of method chaining, so thats why i wanted to kind of separate out the different methods. Thanks for the awesome answer!

Answer (score 1):

No quite convinced of the use case but you can use some *proxy* methods in `SomeClass` (use `property` whenever needed) to delegate the calls to the respective `Test` methods:

```
In [343]: class Test(object): 
     ...:     def __init__(self, a): 
     ...:         self.a = a 
     ...:  
     ...:     def methoda(self): 
     ...:         return len(self.a) 
     ...:  
     ...:  
     ...: class SomeClass(object): 
     ...:     def __init__(self, lol): 
     ...:         self.lol = lol 
     ...:         self.test = Test(self.lol) 
     ...:      
     ...:     @property 
     ...:     def a(self): 
     ...:         return self.test.a 
     ...:          
     ...:     def length(self): 
     ...:         return self.test.methoda() 
     ...:  
     ...:     def __call__(self): 
     ...:         return self.test 
     ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                   

In [344]: c = SomeClass('bar')                                                                                                                                                                              

In [345]: c.a                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[345]: 'bar'

In [346]: c.length()                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[346]: 3
```

Also note that, you can call the `SomeClass` instance i.e. `c` as you have the `__call_-` method defined, and returns the `Test` instance. That way you can get the values using:

```
In [347]: print(c())                                                                                                                                                                                        
<__main__.Test object at 0x7fba862fc3c8>

In [348]: print(c().a)                                                                                                                                                                                      
bar

In [349]: print(c().methoda())                                                                                                                                                                              
3
```

Answer (score 1):

- For this you need to understand when `__init__` is called and when `__call__` is called.

```py
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self, lol):
        print('__init__ called')
    def __call__(self):
        print('__call__ called')

ob = foo('lol')
print(ob())
_ = foo('lol')()
```

- this will output:

```
__init__ called # ob = foo('lol')
__call__ called # print(ob())
__init__ called # _ = foo('lol')()
__call__ called # _ = foo('lol')()
```

- `__init__` is called when class is instantiate. `__call__` is called when you call that object of class as function.
- To access `Test` class in your case you can do following.

```
c = SomeClass('bar')
test_c = c()
print(c.a)
print(c.methoda)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the `__new__` special method. It allows to build from scratch the object created from the class:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __new__(cls, lol):
        obj = Test(lol)
        return obj
```

You can then use it:

```
>>> c = SomeClass('bar')
>>> c
<__main__.Test object at 0x03F87750>
>>> c.a
'bar'
>>> c.methoda()
3
```

But you should not unless you make `Test` a subclass of `SomeClass`. It is at least uncommon that `SomeClass('bar')` returns an object that is not a `SomeClass`, and you could be burned later because of that...